# How to change pull to refresh icon of tableview in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the pull to refresh icon of tableview

I have succeeded in removing the icon as shown below, but the progress does not go any further.

How can I change the pull to refresh icon?

thank you

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh(refresh:)), for: .valueChanged)
refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clear
tableview.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

Comment: Try this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh

Comment: What do you want instead of the standard activity indicator? `UIRefreshControl` doesn't provide any API to change its look. But maybe you can try adding a label or image view with the desired icon as a subview of the refresh control.